# I'm trying to use a python script to start up multiple programs in a specific sequence - some programs always fail

Tags: python, windows, exe

I am trying to open some programs in a specific sequence
there are several programs I cannot seem to get to open no matter what I do
I'm sure its a simple syntax thing
I just need some help

when I run this script

```
os.startfile('"C:\Program Files\Topten Software\Cantabile 3.0\Cantabile.exe"')
time.sleep(2)
os.startfile('"C:\Program Files\Audiostrom\LiveProfessor 2\LiveProfessor 2.exe"')
time.sleep(5)
os.startfile('"C:\Program Files (x86)\VB\Voicemeeter\voicemeeterpro.exe"')
time.sleep(3)
os.startfile('"C:\Program Files (x86)\MidiKey2Key\MidiKey2Key.exe"')
time.sleep(2)
os.startfile('"C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe"')
time.sleep(5)
os.stsartfile('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mixlr\Mixlr.exe"')
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dropbox/Podcast Python/start podcast.py", line 12, in <module>
    os.startfile('"C:\Program Files (x86)\VB\Voicemeeter\voicemeeterpro.exe"')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VB\\Voicemeeter\x0boicemeeterpro.exe"'
```

as you can see it reports the file name as something different than I have typed in the script

I have also tried using subprocess.Popen() and it gives me errors as well

```
subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files\Topten Software\Cantabile 3.0\Cantabile.exe"')
time.sleep(2)
subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files\Audiostrom\LiveProfessor 2\LiveProfessor 2.exe"')
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files (x86)\VB\Voicemeeter\voicemeeterpro.exe"')
time.sleep(3)
subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files (x86)\MidiKey2Key\MidiKey2Key.exe"')
time.sleep(2)
subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe"')
time.sleep(5)
subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mixlr\Mixlr.exe"')
```

```
  File "D:/Dropbox/Podcast Python/start podcast.py", line 12, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files (x86)\VB\Voicemeeter\voicemeeterpro.exe"')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 1017, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

all Program Names have been a copy and paste from right clicking the actual executable and copying the "Target"

I can paste this value in a command line and the program runs

Comment: You should read the documentation for those functions. Try using `os.system('C:\\Program Files\\...')`.

Comment: os.system doesnt actually open the programs..., I've already tried that

Comment: As I said, read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system `Execute the command (a string) in a subshell.`

Comment: `os.startfile` can run a single executable without parameters, which is convenient for elevating to administrator (i.e. "runas" operation) -- e.g. `os.startfile(sys.executable, 'runas')`. It doesn't allow passing a command line, and in particular the file path should not be a quoted string, and a string literal with backslashes in it should be a [r]aw string -- e.g. `os.startfile(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mixlr\Mixlr.exe')`.